# stream() function PHPOffice/PhpWord

Tags: php, laravel, phpword

I want to use PHPOffice/PHPWord to generate a word file in Laravel 5.2. This is working great! Only thing is, I would like to stream the file. Or, when the user chooses to generate a word document, it automatically opens.

I looked inside the WriterInterface.php and the only function possible is the save function. Does anyone know how to implicate a stream or open function?

```
$objWriter->open('../public/uploads/helloWorld.docx');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the file to a temporary folder, then use the download function [@laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses#file-downloads)

Comment: If it works for you accept the answer @AnnaJeanine :)